# match all the contents of a list in restrictions in hibernate query

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to achieve above requirement.

I have a class like

```
public class Test{private String id;private List<Items> items;}
```

Item class like

```
public class Item{private String name; private String state;}
```

I want to query all item's states in a particular restriction group.

Let's say.

There are states like {Done,Done need to confirm,Reject}

and I want to have a query the all the item's states in {Done,Done need to confirm} group.

If there's is a one item's state not in above states should not give as a result for the query.

I check with this kind of thing.I want to know whether i'm doing this correctly or way to do it.

`criteria.add(Restrictions.in("item.state", states));`

Answer (score 2):

Using the criteria like you tried:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.in("item.state", states));
```

will give you the following error

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: item of: Test
```

This is because you don't have an "item" property in your Test class.

To make it work, you need to create an alias for your Item and use it in your restriction:

```
Criteria crit = hibSession.createCriteria(Test.class);
crit.createAlias("items", "item_");
crit.add(Restrictions.in("item_.state", states));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But will this only return the Test object that all states in the restrictions.I guess no.This will return the Test object either one state in the Test  states in restriction states.I want query which return the Test object when all the states in each Test object in restrictions group.Thank you!